# unzip in powershell doesn't clean temporary files

Tags: powershell, unzip, temporary, temp, temporary-files

I've been using the function powershell to unzip a large number of files:

```
    function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
    {
      $shell = new-object -com shell.application
      $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
      foreach($item in $zip.items())
      {
        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
      }
    }
```

Which I call using something like:

```
Expand-ZIPFile -File "$dir\$zip_file" -Destination $work_dir
```

I found that this process in creating a temporary file in 
C:\Documents and Settings\ftpuser\Local Settings\Temp

for each one of these files I unzip, and over the past month it has generated close to 800GB of temporary files.

Question: Is there a way to

1. Stop the unzip process from creating a temporary file in the first place?
2. Force my script to clean up these files before exiting?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this behavior in Windows 7. This was also observed [here](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2217442). Not ideal but i suppose you could empty recent files from the %temp% directory. Say.. edited last 10 minutes?

Comment: I would note that the Shell.Application hack for creating or extracting zip files is not automation-friendly (no status checking, it is asynchronous, etc.). See here: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/760ea95b-4c3e-4f48-a0f6-9d728d5580da/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/760ea95b-4c3e-4f48-a0f6-9d728d5580da/). 99% of the time is it much simpler to just use a command-line unzip tool such as [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org).

Answer (score 0):

Lazy solution:

```
$temp = "C:\Documents and Settings\ftpuser\Local Settings\Temp\"
rm "$temp$($item.Title)"
```

Answer (score 0):

My Lazy solution (automated):

```
    $temp_dir = "C:\Documents and Settings\ftpuser\Local Settings\Temp"
    $temp_listing = Get-ChildItem $temp_dir -include *zip -recurse -force | Select-Object Name
    if ( $temp_listing -ne $null ) {
      foreach ($item in $temp_listing) {
        $item -match "Name=(.+)}"
        $item = $Matches[1]
        Write-Host "Removing $temp_dir\$item"
        if (Test-Path -Path "$temp_dir\$item" -PathType Container)
        {
          Remove-Item "$temp_dir\$item" -recurse -force
        }
      }
    }
```

This works so that the script:

1. finds the hidden files
2. does not prompt
3. can still run inside of a scheduled task.

Thanks